# Service argument based on console command argument

Tags: php, symfony

I have situation where I have several entity managers like

```
  entity_manager_en
  entity_manager_us
  entity_manager_pl
```

etc.

Each entity manager refers to database with different language content.

I have command, where required argument is lang (language).
I also have service which as constructor argument require entity manager.

Is it possible to somehow create dynamically entity manager based on lang given in command and pass it as my service argument while it is creating?

I tried with ConsoleCommandEvent but it fires before input contain arguments...

Comment: What about showing us the code you have already and what you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want call entity manager in `execute` method in your command you can get argument and add it to `getManager()` method:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $lang = $input->getArgument('lang');

    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager('entity_manager_' . $lang);

    ...
}
```